# Separating DC Cables and Communication Cables in the same trunking (Solar Installation)

Tags: dc, digital-communications, solar-energy

There is an upcoming project which requires me to install the communication cables together with the DC cables for the PV modules. Each of the PV modules will have an additional communication device added for safety purposes. As we are using a covered GI trunking to lay the DC cables along the rooftop, the supplier has suggested to lay the rs485 cables in the GI conduit (not GI flexible conduit) and to be placed inside the same trunking used for the DC cables. There will be a total 5 communication cables and these 5 must be individually separated as well into 5 GI conduits which is suggested by the supplier. The reason for the use of GI conduit is to prevent the DC cables from interfering with the communication cable and the few communication cables from interfering each other as well (crosstalk).

This is practical but the cost is pretty high, would like to ask if anyone has a better suggestion to isolate the comm cable and the DC cable while having both placed into the same trunking. And if not, any other cost-efficient ways to go about this?

Comment: I would imagine DC cables are interference-safe since you need a changing current to cause interference. A steady current creates a steady magnetic field, which doesn't cause interference. However, there is still a risk that a sudden change (e.g. circuit breaker trip) which makes it *not* steady could cause a voltage spike on the communication cable. I am not an expert in this area so don't trust my advice.

Comment: There are cable trays with an additional wall. Alternatively, you could  use a wide tray and lay cables on each side, an gap of 5cm is enough, IMO.Then I would also ask why you need separate RS485, as the goal of this protocol is the use of multidrop, one master / multiple slaves / single RS485 bus.